# Can't find network files over SMB protocol using the Spotlight in Lion

Tags: network, macos, smb, spotlight

I tried to find some files in a network volume mounted in OS X Lion over SMB using Spotlight. Didn't work.

But, when I tried the same search from OS X Snow Leopard it worked perfectly.

What do I need to perform this kind of search? Something to be enabled with the "defaults" command in the CLI?

Answer (score 1):

You have to tell Spotlight to index the volume so you can find the files on it.

Open Terminal and issues the command:

```
sudo mdutil -i on /Volumes/<name of the network_volume you want SL to index>
```

This command should work in every version of macOS from Snow Lion up to El Capitan

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try the free app EasyFind, available from [DEVONtechnologies](http://www.devontechnologies.com/download/products.html) or the App Store.

I tried to insert some screen shots for you but I'm **too much of a newbie**. :-)

It works just fine on Lion. We've been using it at our school as a Spotlight replacement for the past few years and it has been fully tested for our Lion rollout this summer.